# Rest controller con Spring Boot 2 y Kotlin siempre retorna la página de whitelabel

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-boot, gradle, kotlin

La clase principal:

```
package com.talleres.paco.mako

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication

@SpringBootApplication
class MakoApplication

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    SpringApplication.run(MakoApplication::class.java, *args)
}
```

El controlador Rest es:

```
package com.talleres.paco.mako.rrhh.persona.delivery.rest

import io.swagger.annotations.Api
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController
import javax.inject.Inject

import com.talleres.paco.mako.commons.dto.Page
import com.talleres.paco.mako.rrhh.persona.domain.boundary.provide.PersonaCriteriaRequestModel
import com.talleres.paco.mako.rrhh.persona.domain.boundary.provide.PersonaRequestModel
import com.talleres.paco.mako.rrhh.persona.domain.boundary.provide.PersonaResponseModel
import com.talleres.paco.mako.rrhh.persona.domain.entities.Persona
import com.talleres.paco.mako.rrhh.persona.infrastructure.di.PersonaUseCaseFactoryDi
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/rest/personas")
@Api(value = "/api/rest/personas")
class PersonaRest(@Inject var useCaseFactory: PersonaUseCaseFactoryDi) {

    init {
        this.useCaseFactory = useCaseFactory
    }

    @GetMapping("/v1/{id}")
    fun findById(@PathVariable(value = "id") id: String) : ResponseEntity<Persona> {
        val presenter = PersonaRestPresenter()
        val findByIdCommand = useCaseFactory.createFindByIdCommand(presenter, id)
        findByIdCommand.execute()
        return presenter.generateResponse()
    }

}
```

El fichero de propiedades:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/mako
spring.datasource.username=mako
spring.datasource.password=mako
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver
server.port=8080
server.http.port=8080
server.https.port=8443
server.servlet.context-path=/mako
server.servlet.path=/mako
springfox.documentation.swagger.v2.path=/api/rest/swagger.json
# Charset of HTTP requests and responses. Added to the "Content-Type" header if not set explicitly.
spring.http.encoding.charset=UTF-8
# Enable http encoding support.
spring.http.encoding.enabled=true
# Force the encoding to the configured charset on HTTP requests and responses.
spring.http.encoding.force=true
# Jackson
spring.jackson.date-format=yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss
spring.jackson.deserialization.adjust_dates_to_context_time_zone=false
# Mail
spring.mail.host=smtp.server.com
spring.mail.port=25
spring.mail.username=test
spring.mail.password=test
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.starttls.enable=true
# Application
token.expiration.days=30
sign.up.code.expiration.hours=24
mail.messages.from=pr@amb.cat
```

Mi fichero gradle de dependencias:

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        kotlinVersion = '1.2.10'
        springBootVersion = '2.0.0.M7'
        springfoxVersion = '2.7.0'
        swaggerVersion = '1.5.16'
        myBatisVersion = '3.4.5'
        injectVersion = '1'
    }
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url "https://repo.spring.io/snapshot" }
        maven { url "https://repo.spring.io/milestone" }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}")
        classpath("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:${kotlinVersion}")
        classpath("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-allopen:${kotlinVersion}")
    }
}

apply plugin: 'kotlin'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-spring'
apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'

group = 'com.talleres.paco'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = 1.8
compileKotlin {
    kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = "1.8"
}
compileTestKotlin {
    kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = "1.8"
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url "https://repo.spring.io/snapshot" }
    maven { url "https://repo.spring.io/milestone" }
}

sourceSets {
    main {
        kotlin {
            srcDir 'src/main/kotlin'
            srcDir 'src/main/customized/kotlin'
            srcDir 'src/main/generated/kotlin'
        }
    }
    main {
        resources {
            srcDir 'src/main/resources'
            srcDir 'src/main/customized/resources'
            srcDir 'src/main/generated/resources'
        }
    }
    test {
        kotlin {
            srcDir 'src/test/kotlin'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile("javax.inject:javax.inject:${injectVersion}")
    compile("io.swagger:swagger-annotations:${swaggerVersion}")
    compile("io.swagger:swagger-core:${swaggerVersion}")
    compile("io.springfox:springfox-swagger2:${springfoxVersion}")
    compile("io.springfox:springfox-swagger-ui:${springfoxVersion}")
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-hateoas')
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator")
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jdbc")
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")
//  compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security")
    compile("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre8:${kotlinVersion}")
    compile("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect:${kotlinVersion}")
    compile("org.mybatis:mybatis:${myBatisVersion}")
    runtime("org.postgresql:postgresql")
    testCompile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test")
//  testCompile("org.springframework.security:spring-security-test")
}
```

La aplicación arranca correctamente:

```
Connected to the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:60835', transport: 'socket'

  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::             (v2.0.0.M7)

2018-01-05 14:54:34.689  INFO 4528 --- [           main] com.talleres.paco.mako.MakoApplicationKt         : Starting MakoApplicationKt on DESKTOP-52MK0P2 with PID 4528 (D:\Workspaces\Mako2Kotlin\mako\out\production\classes started by jagilberte in D:\Workspaces\Mako2Kotlin\mako)
2018-01-05 14:54:34.705  INFO 4528 --- [           main] com.talleres.paco.mako.MakoApplicationKt         : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2018-01-05 14:54:35.242  INFO 4528 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext@35399441: startup date [Fri Jan 05 14:54:35 CET 2018]; root of context hierarchy
2018-01-05 14:54:35.472  WARN 4528 --- [kground-preinit] o.s.h.c.j.Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder    : For Jackson Kotlin classes support please add "com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-kotlin" to the classpath
2018-01-05 14:54:36.827  WARN 4528 --- [kground-preinit] o.s.h.c.j.Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder    : For Jackson Kotlin classes support please add "com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-kotlin" to the classpath
2018-01-05 14:54:39.228  INFO 4528 --- [           main] f.a.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor : JSR-330 'javax.inject.Inject' annotation found and supported for autowiring
2018-01-05 14:54:39.410  INFO 4528 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$669226a4] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2018-01-05 14:54:40.199  INFO 4528 --- [           main] o.h.v.i.engine.ValidatorFactoryImpl      : HV000238: Temporal validation tolerance set to 0.
2018-01-05 14:54:41.514  INFO 4528 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2018-01-05 14:54:41.540  INFO 4528 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2018-01-05 14:54:41.540  INFO 4528 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.5.23
2018-01-05 14:54:41.571  INFO 4528 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener   : The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: [C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_144\bin;C:\WINDOWS\Sun\Java\bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\Resources\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Intel\Shared Files\cpp\bin\Intel64;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\apache-maven-3.5.0\bin;C:\Program Files\gradle-4.4.1\bin;C:\Program Files\SourceGear\Common\DiffMerge\;C:\Program Files\AutoFirma\AutoFirma;C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin;C:\Users\jagilberte\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\jagilberte\AppData\Local\atom\bin;C:\Users\jagilberte\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;;C:\Users\jagilberte\AppData\Local\Box\Box Edit\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code\bin;.]
2018-01-05 14:54:41.773  INFO 4528 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/mako]   : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2018-01-05 14:54:41.773  INFO 4528 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 6539 ms
2018-01-05 14:54:42.080  WARN 4528 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.h.c.j.Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder    : For Jackson Kotlin classes support please add "com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-kotlin" to the classpath
2018-01-05 14:54:42.597  INFO 4528 --- [ost-startStop-1] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/api/rest/personas/v1],methods=[POST]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<com.talleres.paco.mako.rrhh.persona.domain.boundary.provide.PersonaResponseModel>   com.talleres.paco.mako.rrhh.persona.delivery.rest.PersonaRest.update(com.talleres.paco.mako.rrhh.persona.domain.boundary.provide.PersonaRequestModel)
2018-01-05 14:54:42.597  INFO 4528 --- [ost-startStop-1] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/api/rest/personas/v1/{id}],methods=[DELETE]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<java.lang.Integer> com.talleres.paco.mako.rrhh.persona.delivery.rest.PersonaRest.delete(java.lang.String)
2018-01-05 14:54:42.597  INFO 4528 --- [ost-startStop-1] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/api/rest/personas/v1],methods=[PUT]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<com.talleres.paco.mako.rrhh.persona.domain.boundary.provide.PersonaResponseModel> com.talleres.paco.mako.rrhh.persona.delivery.rest.PersonaRest.insert(com.talleres.paco.mako.rrhh.persona.domain.boundary.provide.PersonaRequestModel)
2018-01-05 14:54:42.597  INFO 4528 --- [ost-startStop-1] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/api/rest/personas/v1/{id}],methods=[GET]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<com.talleres.paco.mako.rrhh.persona.domain.entities.Persona> com.talleres.paco.mako.rrhh.persona.delivery.rest.PersonaRest.findById(java.lang.String)
2018-01-05 14:54:42.597  INFO 4528 --- [ost-startStop-1] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/api/rest/personas/v1/findByCriteria],methods=[POST]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<java.util.List<com.talleres.paco.mako.rrhh.persona.domain.entities.Persona>> com.talleres.paco.mako.rrhh.persona.delivery.rest.PersonaRest.findByCriteria(com.talleres.paco.mako.rrhh.persona.domain.boundary.provide.PersonaCriteriaRequestModel)
2018-01-05 14:54:42.597  INFO 4528 --- [ost-startStop-1] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/api/rest/personas/v1/deleteByCriteria],methods=[POST]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<java.lang.Integer> com.talleres.paco.mako.rrhh.persona.delivery.rest.PersonaRest.deleteByCriteria(com.talleres.paco.mako.rrhh.persona.domain.boundary.provide.PersonaCriteriaRequestModel)
2018-01-05 14:54:42.613  INFO 4528 --- [ost-startStop-1] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/api/rest/personas/v1/findByPageCriteria],methods=[POST]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<com.talleres.paco.mako.commons.dto.Page<com.talleres.paco.mako.rrhh.persona.domain.entities.Persona>> com.talleres.paco.mako.rrhh.persona.delivery.rest.PersonaRest.findByPageCriteria(com.talleres.paco.mako.rrhh.persona.domain.boundary.provide.PersonaCriteriaRequestModel)
2018-01-05 14:54:42.628  INFO 4528 --- [ost-startStop-1] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/error]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.Object>> org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.BasicErrorController.error(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest)
2018-01-05 14:54:42.628  INFO 4528 --- [ost-startStop-1] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/error],produces=[text/html]}" onto public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.BasicErrorController.errorHtml(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse)
2018-01-05 14:54:42.808  INFO 4528 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/webjars/**] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2018-01-05 14:54:42.808  INFO 4528 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/**] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2018-01-05 14:54:42.918  INFO 4528 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/**/favicon.ico] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2018-01-05 14:54:45.429  INFO 4528 --- [ost-startStop-1] s.b.a.e.w.s.WebMvcEndpointHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/actuator/health],methods=[GET],produces=[application/vnd.spring-boot.actuator.v2+json || application/json]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.web.servlet.WebMvcEndpointHandlerMapping$OperationHandler.handle(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.String>)
2018-01-05 14:54:45.429  INFO 4528 --- [ost-startStop-1] s.b.a.e.w.s.WebMvcEndpointHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/actuator/info],methods=[GET],produces=[application/vnd.spring-boot.actuator.v2+json || application/json]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.web.servlet.WebMvcEndpointHandlerMapping$OperationHandler.handle(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.String>)
2018-01-05 14:54:45.429  INFO 4528 --- [ost-startStop-1] s.b.a.e.w.s.WebMvcEndpointHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/actuator],methods=[GET],produces=[application/vnd.spring-boot.actuator.v2+json || application/json]}" onto private java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.util.Map<java.lang.String, org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.web.Link>> org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.web.servlet.WebMvcEndpointHandlerMapping.links(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest)
2018-01-05 14:54:45.582  INFO 4528 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.ServletRegistrationBean  : Mapping servlet: 'dispatcherServlet' to [/mako/*]
2018-01-05 14:54:45.582  INFO 4528 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'webMetricsFilter' to: [/*]
2018-01-05 14:54:45.582  INFO 4528 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'characterEncodingFilter' to: [/*]
2018-01-05 14:54:45.582  INFO 4528 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'hiddenHttpMethodFilter' to: [/*]
2018-01-05 14:54:45.582  INFO 4528 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'httpPutFormContentFilter' to: [/*]
2018-01-05 14:54:45.582  INFO 4528 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'requestContextFilter' to: [/*]
2018-01-05 14:54:45.582  INFO 4528 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'webRequestLoggingFilter' to: [/*]
2018-01-05 14:54:45.758  INFO 4528 --- [           main] o.s.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy          : Final method [public final org.springframework.jdbc.core.namedparam.NamedParameterJdbcOperations com.talleres.paco.mako.commons.repository.impl.RepositoryJdbc.getNamedParameterJdbcOperations()] cannot get proxied via CGLIB: Calls to this method will NOT be routed to the target instance and might lead to NPEs against uninitialized fields in the proxy instance.
2018-01-05 14:54:45.758  INFO 4528 --- [           main] o.s.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy          : Final method [public final void com.talleres.paco.mako.commons.repository.impl.RepositoryJdbc.setNamedParameterJdbcOperations(org.springframework.jdbc.core.namedparam.NamedParameterJdbcOperations)] cannot get proxied via CGLIB: Calls to this method will NOT be routed to the target instance and might lead to NPEs against uninitialized fields in the proxy instance.
2018-01-05 14:54:45.758  INFO 4528 --- [           main] o.s.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy          : Final method [protected final java.sql.Connection org.springframework.jdbc.core.support.JdbcDaoSupport.getConnection() throws org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException] cannot get proxied via CGLIB: Calls to this method will NOT be routed to the target instance and might lead to NPEs against uninitialized fields in the proxy instance.
2018-01-05 14:54:45.758  INFO 4528 --- [           main] o.s.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy          : Final method [public final org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate org.springframework.jdbc.core.support.JdbcDaoSupport.getJdbcTemplate()] cannot get proxied via CGLIB: Calls to this method will NOT be routed to the target instance and might lead to NPEs against uninitialized fields in the proxy instance.
2018-01-05 14:54:45.758  INFO 4528 --- [           main] o.s.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy          : Final method [public final void org.springframework.jdbc.core.support.JdbcDaoSupport.setJdbcTemplate(org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate)] cannot get proxied via CGLIB: Calls to this method will NOT be routed to the target instance and might lead to NPEs against uninitialized fields in the proxy instance.
2018-01-05 14:54:45.758  INFO 4528 --- [           main] o.s.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy          : Final method [public final void org.springframework.jdbc.core.support.JdbcDaoSupport.setDataSource(javax.sql.DataSource)] cannot get proxied via CGLIB: Calls to this method will NOT be routed to the target instance and might lead to NPEs against uninitialized fields in the proxy instance.
2018-01-05 14:54:45.758  INFO 4528 --- [           main] o.s.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy          : Final method [public final javax.sql.DataSource org.springframework.jdbc.core.support.JdbcDaoSupport.getDataSource()] cannot get proxied via CGLIB: Calls to this method will NOT be routed to the target instance and might lead to NPEs against uninitialized fields in the proxy instance.
2018-01-05 14:54:45.758  INFO 4528 --- [           main] o.s.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy          : Final method [protected final org.springframework.jdbc.support.SQLExceptionTranslator org.springframework.jdbc.core.support.JdbcDaoSupport.getExceptionTranslator()] cannot get proxied via CGLIB: Calls to this method will NOT be routed to the target instance and might lead to NPEs against uninitialized fields in the proxy instance.
2018-01-05 14:54:45.758  INFO 4528 --- [           main] o.s.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy          : Final method [protected final void org.springframework.jdbc.core.support.JdbcDaoSupport.releaseConnection(java.sql.Connection)] cannot get proxied via CGLIB: Calls to this method will NOT be routed to the target instance and might lead to NPEs against uninitialized fields in the proxy instance.
2018-01-05 14:54:45.758  WARN 4528 --- [           main] o.s.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy          : Unable to proxy interface-implementing method [public final void org.springframework.dao.support.DaoSupport.afterPropertiesSet() throws java.lang.IllegalArgumentException,org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanInitializationException] because it is marked as final: Consider using interface-based JDK proxies instead!
2018-01-05 14:54:45.773  INFO 4528 --- [           main] o.s.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy          : Final method [public final void org.springframework.dao.support.DaoSupport.afterPropertiesSet() throws java.lang.IllegalArgumentException,org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanInitializationException] cannot get proxied via CGLIB: Calls to this method will NOT be routed to the target instance and might lead to NPEs against uninitialized fields in the proxy instance.
2018-01-05 14:54:45.961  INFO 4528 --- [           main] o.h.v.i.engine.ValidatorFactoryImpl      : HV000238: Temporal validation tolerance set to 0.
2018-01-05 14:54:46.211  WARN 4528 --- [           main] o.s.h.c.j.Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder    : For Jackson Kotlin classes support please add "com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-kotlin" to the classpath
2018-01-05 14:54:46.485  WARN 4528 --- [           main] o.s.h.c.j.Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder    : For Jackson Kotlin classes support please add "com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-kotlin" to the classpath
2018-01-05 14:54:46.564  WARN 4528 --- [           main] o.s.h.c.j.Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder    : For Jackson Kotlin classes support please add "com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-kotlin" to the classpath
2018-01-05 14:54:46.564  WARN 4528 --- [           main] o.s.h.c.j.Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder    : For Jackson Kotlin classes support please add "com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-kotlin" to the classpath
2018-01-05 14:54:46.697  WARN 4528 --- [           main] o.s.h.c.j.Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder    : For Jackson Kotlin classes support please add "com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-kotlin" to the classpath
2018-01-05 14:54:46.775  WARN 4528 --- [           main] o.s.h.c.j.Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder    : For Jackson Kotlin classes support please add "com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-kotlin" to the classpath
2018-01-05 14:54:46.775  INFO 4528 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter : Looking for @ControllerAdvice: org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext@35399441: startup date [Fri Jan 05 14:54:35 CET 2018]; root of context hierarchy
2018-01-05 14:54:46.884  WARN 4528 --- [           main] o.s.h.c.j.Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder    : For Jackson Kotlin classes support please add "com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-kotlin" to the classpath
2018-01-05 14:54:48.024  INFO 4528 --- [           main] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Registering beans for JMX exposure on startup
2018-01-05 14:54:48.027  INFO 4528 --- [           main] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Bean with name 'dataSource' has been autodetected for JMX exposure
2018-01-05 14:54:48.039  INFO 4528 --- [           main] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Located MBean 'dataSource': registering with JMX server as MBean [com.zaxxer.hikari:name=dataSource,type=HikariDataSource]
2018-01-05 14:54:48.202  INFO 4528 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http) with context path '/mako'
2018-01-05 14:54:48.218  INFO 4528 --- [           main] com.talleres.paco.mako.MakoApplicationKt         : Started MakoApplicationKt in 15.086 seconds (JVM running for 16.805)
2018-01-05 14:55:30.532  INFO 4528 --- [io-8080-exec-10] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/mako]   : Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2018-01-05 14:55:30.532  INFO 4528 --- [io-8080-exec-10] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet': initialization started
2018-01-05 14:55:30.582  INFO 4528 --- [io-8080-exec-10] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet': initialization completed in 50 ms
```

Cuando pruebo con la siguiente url en el navegador:
http://localhost:8080/mako/api/rest/personas/v1/1

Obtengo la página de whitelabel de springboot.

Cuando pruebo con esta otra url:
http://localhost:8080/api/rest/personas/v1/1

Obtengo un 404 de tomcat.

La primera url es procesada por la aplicación pero no es tratada por el método que yo he anotado. Simplemente no la reconoce.
Qué está mal en el ejemplo?. Falta alguna anotación más?. Por las trazas de la aplicación sí parece que detecta las anotaciones.

Comment: Ya he encontrado donde está el problema si pongo en el browser: http://localhost;8080/mako/mako/api/rest/personas/v1/1 funciona. El problema debe estar en que he informado dos propiedades que afectan al contexto: servlet.server.path y servlet.server.context-path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema estaba en el properties que debe ser:

```
...
server.servlet.context-path=/mako
springfox.documentation.swagger.v2.path=/api/rest/swagger.json
...
```

Sólo hay que informar el context-path. Si se informa también la otra se concatena.